# Killing Parent and Child processes on Remote with Powershell

Tags: powershell, process

I'm attempting to kill a parent process and it's child process (There will only be one child) on a remote computer.  When executing this script (Which is part of a larger one) i get the following error. PowerShell Newbie, so any suggestions for improvement beyond solving the error are most welcome.

```
Cannot bind parameter 'Process'. Cannot convert the "Kill-ChildProcess" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock".
        + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [ForEach-Object], ParameterBindingException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ForEachObjectCommand
```

Script:

```
$scriptBlock =  {                 
        function Kill-ChildProcess(){
            param($ID=$PID)
                $CustomColumnID = @{
                Name = 'Id'
                Expression = { [Int[]]$_.ProcessID }
                }

                Write-Host $ID
                $result = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process -Filter "ParentProcessID=$ID" |
                Select-Object -Property ProcessName, $CustomColumnID, CommandLine

                $result | Where-Object { $_.ID -ne $null } | Stop-Process
        }


         Get-Process $args[0] -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | ForEach Kill-ChildProcess -id {$_.ID};
         Get-Process $args[0] -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Stop-Process -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
    };


Invoke-Command -Session $session  -ArgumentList $processToKill -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock
```

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't enumerate the process tree, so processes spawned by sub-processes will be excluded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error your getting is because the following line is improperly expressed:

```
Get-Process $args[0] -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | ForEach Kill-ChildProcess -id {$_.ID};
```

The error is trying (in microsoft fashion) to tell you that it needs a script block after a `ForEach`.  Replace the line with the following to continue past that error:

```
Get-Process $args[0] -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | ForEach {Kill-ChildProcess -id $_.ID}
```

Also, just an aside, but powershell does not require line terminators unless you're processing multiple commands on the same line in the shell.  In short, you don't need to end every line with `;`.

Comment: Cheers! Will check when i get back to work tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 1):

After your `ForEach-Object (or aliases: ForEach, %)` place the code which follows into curly braces `{}`.

So change this line from what you have:

```
Get-Process $args[0] -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | ForEach Kill-ChildProcess -id {$_.ID};
```

to this, which correctly places the curly braces around the code after `ForEach-Object`:

```
 Get-Process $args[0] -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | ForEach { Kill-ChildProcess -id $_.ID }
```

Let us know if that resolves that specific error message you posted.

---

Also, here is some information on using `ForEach-Object` for your reference:

> Beginning in Windows PowerShell 3.0, there are two different ways to
>   construct a `ForEach-Object` command.
>
> **Script block.**
>
> You can use a script block to specify the operation. Within the script
>   block, use the `$_` variable to represent the current object. The
>   script block is the value of the Process parameter. The script block
>   can contain any Windows PowerShell script.
>
> For example, the following command gets the value of the ProcessName
>   property of each process on the computer.
>
> ```
> Get-Process | ForEach-Object {$_.ProcessName}
> ```
>
> **Operation statement**.
>
> You can also write a operation statement, which is much more like
>   natural language. You can use the operation statement to specify a
>   property value or call a method. Operation statements were introduced
>   in Windows PowerShell 3.0.
>
> For example, the following command also gets the value of the
>   ProcessName property of each process on the computer.
>
> ```
> Get-Process | ForEach-Object ProcessName
> ```
>
> When using the script block format, in addition to using the script
>   block that describes the operations that are performed on each input
>   object, you can provide two additional script blocks. The `Begin`
>   script block, which is the value of the Begin parameter, runs before
>   the first input object is processed. The `End` script block, which is
>   the value of the End parameter, runs after the last input object is
>   processed.

Comment: Thank you, that solved it (as did the other first answer)